# Unable to update action bar items with invalidateOptionsMenu() in a Fragment after orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I have number of fragments in a root activity which I set them true for retaining their instances on config changes.
However, this arises a serious issue for me;

I have an AsyncTask in my Fragment.onResume(...) which performs a background job and calls     getSherlockActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu(...) method to change the action bar items. When the app first opens fragment worked as expected and invalidating options menu recalls Fragment.oncreateOptionMenu(...) method. But when I change the orientation, AsyncTask is started again and does this background job but invalidating doesn't call Fragment.oncreateOptionMenu(...) so my action bar remains in an unwanted state.

This is my task;

```
private class ContactListLoader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Log.d("Contact List Fragment", "Task started...");
        ContactListFragment.mIsRunning = true;
        if (emptyView != null) {
            if (emptyView instanceof TextView) {
                ((TextView) emptyView).setText(getResources().getString(
                        R.string.contact_list_loading_list_title));
            }
        }
        getSherlockActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        getSherlockActivity().setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(
                true);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        createDataSet();
        ContactListFragment.mIsRunning = false;
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        mContactsListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mIsContactsLoadedFirstTime = true;
        if (emptyView != null) {
            if (emptyView instanceof TextView) {
                ((TextView) emptyView).setText(getResources().getString(
                        R.string.contact_list_empty_list_title));
            }
        }
        getSherlockActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        getSherlockActivity().setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(
                false);
        if (mContactsLocal != null & !mContactsLocal.isEmpty()) {
            listener.onContactListLoaded(mContactsLocal.get(0),
                    mContactsLocal);
        }

        try {
            if (mCapabilityApi != null
                    && mCapabilityApi.isImsConnected(getSherlockActivity()
                            .getApplicationContext())) {
                mCapabilityApi.refreshAllCapabilities();
            }
        } catch (ClientApiException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Toast.makeText(getSherlockActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                getResources().getString(R.string.contact_list_updated),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        Log.d("Contact List Fragment", "task cancelled 2");
        ContactListFragment.mIsRunning = false;
        super.onCancelled();
    }

}
```

Any ideas?